# MS Access: query only one criteria in multiple criteria lookup field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a MS Access database that has a multiple criteria lookup field with entries like:

```
ID  Names
1   Carl, Daniel
2   Natalia
3   Carl, Natalia
4   Natalia, Carl
5   Carl
6   Natalia
7   Bob
8   Bob
9   Bob, Natalia
```

I would like to write a query that only results in:

```
2   Natalia
6   Natalia
```

I tried this code and it isn't working:

```
WHERE (((Table.Name)="Natalia"));
```

This provides all the instances that include Natalia:

```
2   Natalia
3   Carl, Natalia
4   Natalia, Carl
6   Natalia
9   Bob, Natalia
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: There must be more to it than you are sharing, perhaps asterisk's in the criteria, because `yourField.yourTable="Natalia"` will **not** return records `where yourTable="Bob,Natalia"`.  Also, note that all of ((those((brackets)))) aren't actually doing anything (I know, they were probably put there by Access; I'm just trying to simplify it for you!)

Comment: Thanks, ashleedawg, for your comment. The names column is an Access "Lookup Column" that has a relationship with a table of all the names (Carl, Daniel, Natalia, Bob). I wasn't sure that was relevant but I guess it's not clear enough in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following line of code:

```
    HAVING (((Names)="Natalia") AND ((Count(Staffers))=1));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not be storing lists a delimnited strings.  The right way is a junction table, with one row per name.

Second, your `WHERE` clause (with the column name fixed) should do what you want:

```
WHERE Names = "Natalia"
```

If you wanted all those other rows, you would use `LIKE`:

```
WHERE Names LIKE "*Natalia*"
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon, for your idea. The Names column is an Access "Lookup Column" that has a relationship with a table of all the names (Carl, Daniel, Natalia, Bob). I think that's why {WHERE Names = "Natalia"} won't work.

Comment: When I run {WHERE Names = "Natalia"} I get:
2   Natalia
3   Carl, Natalia
4   Natalia, Carl
6   Natalia
9   Bob, Natalia